# How to ADD Decimal to Time in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula

Is it possible to make a formula that will take a value from a column that is a Time format and add a Decimal from another column that will evaluate to a new Time format? Is so, how?

For example:

```
  _________________________________________________
  |     A          |        B       |      C       |
  --------------------------------------------------
1 | Departure Time | Hours Duration | Arrival Time |
2 | 7:00 AM        | 2.78           | =SUM(A2+B2)  |
3 | 7:00 AM        | 1.33           | =SUM(A3+B3)  |
4 | 7:00 AM        | 6.98           | =SUM(A4+B4)  |
5 | 7:00 AM        | 2.50           | 9:30 AM      |
```

The Hours Duration column above is in Decimal Format and the Departure and Arrival Time columns are in Time Format (h:mm am/pm). Note in Row 5 the Hours Duration is "2.50" which is 2 hours and 30 minutes (not 2 hours and 50 minutes) - So (7:00 AM + 2.50) should result in 9:30 AM.

The formula's in Column C in the above example do not work, but are just examples to hopefully give you an idea as to what I'm hoping to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **C2**

```
=A2 + B2/24
```

and format **C2** in *Time* format.